# How to use Struts2 interceptor for each request redirecting to https instead of http

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, interceptor

I am developing jsp,struts2 web application in which i want only HTTPS.
So can you please tell me how can do this with struts2 interceptor.
Please dont suggest tomcat configuration or web.xml file changes as i am not happy with that solution.
I want it only in struts2 interceptor

Does anybody have idea for this (this should be kind of filter which will be executed for every request complesory)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What should be done in interceptor, what you are expecting?

Comment: Just want it should redirect the http request to https nothing else

Comment: Hey @JMoh did you implement this intercept in Struts2?

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement of having a https instead of http IMHO is clearly a web.xml security measure, it has nothing to do with Struts2.

To redirect EVERY request to HTTPS instead of HTTP, simple put the below code in your web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>All Under HTTPS</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: So using the above tag in web.xml doesn't meet your needs ? Because I used this in my struts2 project and it works perfect - It redirects all requests to HTTPS.

Comment: It works perfectly but for some other reasons i want it in interceptors may be like filter.

Comment: I tried thinking but don't find a reason for such a requirement, may be if you can tell your requirement, a good alternative can be sought.